# search page not displaying any results

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

please assist

I have created a search page to query the database, when the submit button is selected, no data is populated into the grid and there is no error message or notice that gives me an indication of where the issue is.  Please assist. 
Here is the code:

```
 <?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
        $txtLastName            = $_POST['txtLastName'];
        $txtidnumber            = $_POST['txtidnumber'];
        $txtMedicalAidNumber    = $_POST['txtMedicalAidNumber'];

        //connect  to the database 
        $db = mysql_connect  
        ("server", "username",  "password") or die ('I   cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error()); 
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) 
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
            $mydb = mysql_select_db("mediouqp_login"); 

       if($txtLastName != '' && $txtidnumber != '' && $txtMedicalAidNumber != '') 
    {
          $sql = "SELECT last_name, id_number, medical_id_number FROM patient WHERE last_name LIKE '%" . $txtLastName .  "%' OR id_number LIKE '%" . $txtidnumber ."%'"; 
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "SELECT last_name FROM patient ORDER BY last_name DESC"; 
    }

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }

    if($result)
    {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
    echo 'Total records found are- '.mysql_num_rows($result);
        }
    else
        {

    echo "No records found.";
        }   
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
   <li><a href="search_patient.php">PATIENT DETAILS</a>
  <li><a href="reports.php">REPORTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="admin.php">ADMINISTRATOR</a></li>
  <li><a href="downloads.php">DOWNLOADS</a></li>
</ul>
    <div class="headerTitle">
    <h1 id="mainHeader">search patient details</h1>
</div>

    <form action="search_patient.php" method="post" name="frm_search" id="frm_search">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="Label" id="lname">Last Name
                                </td>
                                <td class="Field">
                                    <input type ="lastname" name ="txtLastName" ></input>
                                    <span id="spnLastName"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="Label" id="lname">ID Number
                                </td>
                                <td class="Field">
                                    <input type ="lastname" name ="txtidnumber" ></input>
                                    <span id="spnIdNumber"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="Label" id="lname">Medical Aid Number
                                </td>
                                <td class="Field">
                                    <input type ="medicalaidnumber" name ="txtMedicalAidNumber" ></input>
                                    <span id="spnMedicalaidNumber"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="Label">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <input type="submit" id="btnSearchPatient" value="Submit"></input>
                                <input type = "button" onClick="window.location='create_patient.php';" value="Create Patient" /></input>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <table id="tblpatient" class="Grid">
                    <tr class="Header">
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>Last Name</td>
                            <td>ID Number</td>
                            <td>Medical Aid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    if($result)
                    {
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

                            { 
                                $last_name          = $row['last_name']; 
                                $id_number          = $row['id_number'];
                                $medical_id_number  = 0;//$row['medical_id_number'];
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><?php echo $last_name;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $id_number;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $medical_id_number;?></td>
                                </tr>    
                                <?php
                            } 
                    }
                    ?>

    </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli` (OOP-style) and `mysql_*`. Stick to `mysqli` since `mysql_*` have been deprecated for years...

Comment: echo the $sql variable and run it direct in MySQL and see if it returns data.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries.`mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not as secure as one would hope.

Comment: Other (valid) observations aside, the main reason that _nothing_ is happening is that your submit button does not have a `name="submit"` attribute, so `isset($_POST['submit'])` will be false.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: This extension(`mysql`) was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used along with prepared statements.

As per the code you have written it will be submitting the data but what you have written under this statement will never Work.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){// Codes Inside this}
```

> Reason this code will not work

- Your Submit button is not having the name which you have given in the `isset($_POST['submit'])`.
- You mist add the name to the submit button which you have in your code.

Replace your Submit button as i have provided by adding the name to it and changing the button code style.

**Replace:**

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSearchPatient" value="Submit"></input>
```

**With:**

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSearchPatient" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

After all the above steps that has been provided ensure the note below in order the data comes as not expected.

> Note: If you need to execute the statement perfect you first put **echo** to the select statement that you have coded and break the execution over there. You will find the `SQL statement` over to the browser and you copy that echoed statement into the SQL section of the DB created in the `Phpmyadmin` and check whether your code executed well. If so you  got the required output that you can remove the echo and exit statement and you can proceed.